# How do I delete a folder where argument list is too long?

Tags: windows-vista

The folder I am trying to delete has sub folders and those sub folders have their child folders. So, it's a huge tree of folders. Please advise.

Comment: I've never seen a path where it was too long to delete :) ..how deeply do you need to `cd` into the tree before running `rd /q/s <folder>` works properly?

Answer (score 6):

```
rmdir /S [Directory]
```

Removes all directories and files in the specified directory
in addition to the directory itself.  Used to remove a directory
tree.

Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: It still says something like File is too long..